# Fixing slow response time for resources

Tags: image, performance, magento, cdn, magento-1.5

I have a Magento website and I have been noticing an increase in warnings from Catchpoint that various images, CSS files, and javascript files are taking longer than usual to load.  We use Edgecast for our CDN and have all images, CSS, and JS files hosted there.  I have been in contact with them and they determined that the delays happen when the cache for the resource has expired and it must contact the origin for an updated file.  The problem is that I can't figure out why it would take longer than a second to return a small image file.  If I load the offending image off our server (not from the CDN) in my browser it always returns quickly.  I assume that if you call up an image file directly using the full URL to the image file (say a product image, for example), that would bypass any Magento logic or database access and simply return the image to you.  This should happen quickly, and it normally does, but sometimes it doesn't.

We have a number of things in play that may have an effect.  There are API calls to the server for various integrations, though they are directed at a secondary server and not the web frontend.  We may also have a large number of stale images since Magento doesn't delete any images even if you replace them or delete the product.

I realize this is a fairly open ended question, and I'm sorry if it breaks SO protocol, but I'm grasping at straws here.  If anyone has any ideas on where to look or what could cause small resource files, like images, to take upwards of 8 seconds to load, I'm all ears.  As an eCommerce site, it's getting close to peak season, and I can feel the hot breath of management on my neck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What do your server logs have to say about the slow fetches from EdgeCast's servers?

Comment: Interestingly, I checked the server logs and do not see any requests made to our site for a recent slow image load from Catchpoint.  This goes against what Edgecast said, since I assume any request made to our site to update the CDN cache would be logged in the Apache transfer log.  I have followed up with Edgecast and our hosting provider with this information.  I'll update or close this question once I get more information from them.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we had stumbled upon some problems with the CDN that they were somewhat aware of and not quick to admit.  They made some changes to our account to work around the issues and things are much better now.